# How can one reset one variable in Javascript and playing an alert after a specific time?

Tags: javascript, alert, setinterval

I am trying to program a little game that should reload after 5 seconds and tell people that they were too slow. Moreover, the variable points should be reset, so that they can start from new. 
With

```
 setInterval(function(){
                window.location.href = "javascript:window.top.location.reload(true)";
            }, 5000);
```

the whole website is loaded and people have to begin from scratch. The same happens when they press command+R.

I tried now to reset the variable points and show the alert that they were too slow.

```
 setInterval(function(){
                alert("You were too slow!");
                 points = 0; 
            }, 5000);
```

If I use this code, then the alert keeps on popping up very quickly. How can I reset everything and only get the alert every 5 seconds?

Comment: Your function seems to be working fine. It is showing alert in 5 seconds what is the problem here?

Comment: Yes, the alert is popping up not just once, but after 5 seconds keeps on popping up whenever I close it.

Comment: Its because user (you here) can take more then 5 seconds to close the alert box and in the mean time, another alert box is ready to pop up.

Comment: Yes, because you have used setInterval which will be call the function after every 5 secs.

Comment: The new alert box is shown 5 seconds after the previous was shown (not 5 seconds after is was dismissed). You might want to use something other than an alert box (a modal, for example), where you can capture a click event to set a timeout instead.

Comment: Here a link to what is happening: https://unipark.de/uc/ch_sg_uni_zbm/a571/ I cannot close the popup anymore (the one appearing after 5 seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the browser the internal timer will continue running while the modal is displayed like in Firefox, or freez like in Chrome. So in Firefox if the modal stays open longer then 5 seconds, then the next one will be showed immediatily after the current one is closed.

There are only rare cases where you really want to use `setInterval` even if you have events that happen in regular intervals you most of the time should use `setTimeout` instead.

```
var roundTimeoutTimer;

function tookToLong() {
   alert("You were too slow!");
   points = 0; 
}

function startTask() {
   roundTimeoutTimer = setTimeout(tookToLong, 5000)
}

function finishedTask() {
   clearTimeout(roundTimeoutTimer)
}
```